# Cannot Scrape Fantasy Table Using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape fantasy player data from the following site: http://www.fplstatistics.co.uk/. The table appears upon opening the site, but it's not visible when I scrape the site.

I tried the following:

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

fplStatsPage = rq.get('http://www.fplstatistics.co.uk')
fplStatsPageSoup = BeautifulSoup(fplStatsPage.text, 'html.parser')
fplStatsPageSoup
```

And the table was nowhere to be seen. What came back in place of where the table should be is:

```
<div>
                The 'Player Data' is out of date.
                <br/> <br/>
                You need to refresh the web page.
                <br/> <br/>
                Press F5 or hit <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
</div>
```

This message appears on the site whenever the table is updated.

I then looked at the developer tools to see if I can find the URL from where the table data is retrieved, but I had no luck. Probably because I don't know how to read the developer tools well.

I then tried to refresh the page as the above message says using Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chromeDriverPath = '/Users/SplitShiftKing/Downloads/Software/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriverPath)
driver.get('http://www.fplstatistics.co.uk')
driver.refresh()
#To give site enough time to refresh
time.sleep(15)
html = driver.page_source
fplStatsPageSoup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
fplStatsPageSoup
```

The output was the same as before. The table appears on the site but not in the output.

Assistance would be appreciated. I've looked at similar questions on overflow, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not go straight to the source that pulls i that data. Only thing you need to work out is the column names, but this gets you all the data in one request and without using selenium:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

s = requests.Session()
url = 'http://www.fplstatistics.co.uk/'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Mobile Safari/537.36'}

response = s.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')
for script in scripts:
    if '"iselRow"' in script.text:
        iselRowVal = re.search('"value":(.+?)}\);}', script.text).group(1).strip()


url = 'http://www.fplstatistics.co.uk/Home/AjaxPricesFHandler'

payload = {
'iselRow': iselRowVal,
'_': ''}


jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['aaData'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.head(5).to_string())
  0               1        2  3  4    5    6      7  8    9      10     11     12  13  14              15                                                16
0            Mustafi  Arsenal  D  A  0.3  5.2  £5.2m  0  ---    110  -95.6  -95.6  -1  -1         Mustafi  Everton(A) Bournemouth(A) Chelsea(H) Man Utd(H) 
1           Bellerín  Arsenal  D  I  0.3  5.4  £5.4m  0  ---  54024    2.6    2.6  -2  -2        Bellerin  Everton(A) Bournemouth(A) Chelsea(H) Man Utd(H) 
2          Kolasinac  Arsenal  D  I  0.6  5.2  £5.2m  0  ---   5464  -13.9  -13.9  -2  -2       Kolasinac  Everton(A) Bournemouth(A) Chelsea(H) Man Utd(H) 
3     Maitland-Niles  Arsenal  D  A  2.6  4.6  £4.6m  0  ---  11924  -39.0  -39.0  -2  -2  Maitland-Niles  Everton(A) Bournemouth(A) Chelsea(H) Man Utd(H) 
4           Sokratis  Arsenal  D  S  1.5  4.9  £4.9m  0  ---  19709  -29.4  -29.4  -2  -2        Sokratis  Everton(A) Bournemouth(A) Chelsea(H) Man Utd(H)
```

Comment: Hey chitown88, thanks for the response but this didn't work for me. It says the data frame is empty when I print. And there's basically nothing when I go to the url. How did you find that url?

Comment: hmmm interesting. I made a modification above. Can you try that and see what happens? (I found that url through the Dev Tools (Ctrl-Shft-I)

Comment: Wow, this is great! So where exactly in the DevTools did you find that url? Also, how did you know that the script with the name 'iselRow' was the one that was retrieving the table? And am I right in thinking that the params basically become the query to the url?

Comment: Ya, it takes a little investigative work to find all that info. The `iselRow` part was sort of unique for this one. Ususally the parameters/query isn't dynamic (unless it requires you to have a cookie). But Here's a little tutorial I wrote up for another user that shows essentially how I find the info: [click hear](https://main.weku.io/community-deals/@stats-n-lats/web-scraping-if-site-is-dynamic-generated-by-javascript)

Comment: Your guide says to look for another way to get the data in step 4 if it doesn't appear after double-clicking name. What other way? Selenium? I'm trying to scrape another site.

Comment: ya, selenium or `requests`

Comment: also sometimes, you might find the ajax in "all" tab instead of XHR, but thats rare

Answer (score 1):

By requesting `driver.page_source` you're cancelling out any benefit you get from Selenium: the page source does not contain the table you want. That table is updated dynamically via Javascript after the page has loaded. You need to retrieve the table use methods on your `driver`, rather than using `BeautifulSoup`.  For example:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> d = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> d.get('http://www.fplstatistics.co.uk')
>>> table = d.find_element_by_id('myDataTable')
>>> print('\n'.join(x.text for x in table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')))
Name
Club
Pos
Status
%Owned
Price
Chgs
Unlocks
Delta
Target
Kelly Crystal Palace D A 30.7 £4.3m 0 --- 0
101.0
Rico Bournemouth D A 14.6 £4.3m 0 --- 0
100.9
Baldock Sheffield Utd D A 7.1 £4.8m 0 --- 88 99.8
Rashford Man Utd F A 26.4 £9.0m 0 --- 794 98.6
Son Spurs M A 21.6 £10.0m 0 --- 833 98.5
Henderson Sheffield Utd G A 7.8 £4.7m 0 --- 860 98.4
Grealish Aston Villa M A 8.9 £6.1m 0 --- 1088 98.0
Kane Spurs F A 19.3 £10.9m 0 --- 3961 92.9
Reid West Ham D A 4.6 £3.9m 0 --- 4029 92.7
Richarlison Everton M A 7.7 £7.8m 0 --- 5405 90.3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot larsks! I didn't know about the 'myDataTable' element. How does one get a view of driver that shows the different elements that the site is composed of?

Comment: I just inspected the web page in a browser to find the table id (in this case using the "Developer Tools" feature in Chrome).